# Communication between components in Maquette

Tags: javascript, events, components, communication, maquette

My question is about the communication between components in the [Maquette](http://maquettejs.org/) Javascript framework.

Imagine I have a `Menu` sub-component used in an `Application` component: the `Application` instance would like to know when a menu item is selected in the `Menu` instance in order to swap the main content displayed in the application (for example). In other words, I need a way to communicate between a child component and its parent component. How can this be achieved in Maquette?

Sure, I can pass a callback owned by the application instance to the menu instance, which will be called when an item is selected. But I'm a bit reluctant to do that because the "selection" event is just a "rendering-side" aspect of the menu component, so I would prefer the event not to leak into my `Menu` API, but to stay inside the render function/method instead.

So, I would like to deal with events at the "rendering-side". But I guess it means I have to send a `CustomEvent` from the `Menu`'s render function and register a `CustomEvent` handler inside the `Application`'s render function, right? Is this use-case supported in maquette? Are there other alternatives to `CustomEvent` for my use-case?

Thanks!

PS: question reposted here from ticket [#71](https://github.com/AFASSoftware/maquette/issues/71) in order to get more answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What we usually do is pass callbacks to components that get invoked when items get clicked. A Menu could be constructed with a callback `menuItemClicked(menuItem: MenuItem)` for example. Imho this does not leak any application-specific knowledge into the menu/menuitem. The creator of the menu could do anything inside the callback like routing or changing a variable.

An event system is also certainly possible. I do not recommend using the DOM hierarchy to bubble the events though. I can imagine the `Application` creating the menu using `menu = createMenu(...)` and afterwards calling `menu.addEventListener('itemClicked', navigate)` or something.

Comment: Why don't you recommend using the DOM hierarchy? Because of performance issues?

Comment: I would think that using the DOM hierarchy makes things needlessly complex. But I am curious if that is actually the case. Maybe you could make a jsfiddle or codepen to demonstrate how you would accomplish this?

Comment: I realize that I may also need an event to be triggered if the currently selected item is changed programmatically outside of the click event handler... So it can't just be a rendering-side-only event. I finally think your answer is the way to go.